# Using a UISegmentedControl to change UIPickerView Labels

Tags: ios, swift, function, uipickerview, uisegmentedcontrol

I've attempted to implement a UISegmentedControl in order to use a switch statement for deciding which array should populate a UIPickerView, however this approach which is written in swift hasn't worked as expected.  Has anyone else explored this problem before or may have any ideas to how these functions could work together?

Here is the code so far:

```
    import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    var rejuvenatedEnterprisesEmployees = [
        Employees(name: "Jeffrey Wells", employeeRoles: ["Accountant", "Designer"], departmentID: 0),
        Employees(name: "Victor Atkins", employeeRoles: ["Director of IT", "Sales Stategist"], departmentID: 0),
        Employees(name: "Kelli Hamilton", employeeRoles: ["Director of Sales"], departmentID: 0),
        Employees(name: "Adam Braun", employeeRoles: ["Sales Lead"], departmentID: 1),
        Employees(name: "Brian Cruz", employeeRoles: ["Designer"], departmentID: 1),
        Employees(name: "Kristen Floyd", employeeRoles: ["Developer"], departmentID: 1),
        Employees(name: "Lois Martinez", employeeRoles: ["Curator", "Blogger"], departmentID: 2),
        Employees(name: "Michael Lind", employeeRoles: ["Sales, Administrator"], departmentID: 2),
        Employees(name: "Eric Bay", employeeRoles: ["Database Admin"], departmentID: 2),
        Employees(name: "Brandon Young", employeeRoles: ["Artist"], departmentID: 2)
    ]
    var rejuvenatedEnterprisesVictorsEmployees = [
        Employees(name: "Victor Atkins", employeeRoles: ["Director of IT", "Sales Stategist"], departmentID: 0),
        Employees(name: "Adam Braun", employeeRoles: ["Sales Lead"], departmentID: 1),
        Employees(name: "Brian Cruz", employeeRoles: ["Designer"], departmentID: 1),
        Employees(name: "Kristen Floyd", employeeRoles: ["Developer"], departmentID: 1)
    ]
    var rejuvenatedEnterprisesKellisEmployees = [
        Employees(name: "Kelli Hamilton", employeeRoles: ["Director of Sales"], departmentID: 0),
        Employees(name: "Lois Martinez", employeeRoles: ["Curator", "Blogger"], departmentID: 2),
        Employees(name: "Michael Lind", employeeRoles: ["Sales, Administrator"], departmentID: 2),
        Employees(name: "Eric Bay", employeeRoles: ["Database Admin"], departmentID: 2),
        Employees(name: "Brandon Young", employeeRoles: ["Artist"], departmentID: 2)
    ]
    var squaredEnterprisesEmployees: [String] = ["Jeffrey Wells","Victor Atkins","Kelli Hamilton","Adam Braun","Brian Cruz","Kristen Floyd","Lois Martinez","Michael Lind","Eric Bay","Brandon Young"]

    //UIPicker Scroll component
    let kManagerScrollComponentCount: Int = 1
    let kManagerScrollComponent: Int = 0
    //UIPicker Scroll component

    var chosenManagerScrollView: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(40,0,170,72))

    @IBOutlet weak var employeeListing: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var userTicketLocation: UILabel!
    @IBAction func addEmployee(sender: AnyObject) {


    }

    @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBAction func indexChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex
        {
        case 0:
            func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) ->UIView {
                //var chosenManagerScrollView: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(40,0,170,72))
                chosenManagerScrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
                var jumperCables: [String] = []
                for var i = 0; i < rejuvenatedEnterprisesEmployees.count ; ++i {
                    jumperCables.append(rejuvenatedEnterprisesEmployees[i].name)
                }
                chosenManagerScrollView.text = jumperCables[row]
                return chosenManagerScrollView
            }
        case 1:
            func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) ->UIView {
                //var chosenManagerScrollView: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(40,0,170,72))
                chosenManagerScrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
                var jumperCablez: [String] = []
                for var i = 0; i < rejuvenatedEnterprisesVictorsEmployees.count ; ++i {
                    jumperCablez.append(rejuvenatedEnterprisesVictorsEmployees[i].name)
                }
                chosenManagerScrollView.text = jumperCablez[row]
                return chosenManagerScrollView
            }
        default:
            break; 
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return kManagerScrollComponentCount
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return rejuvenatedEnterprisesEmployees.count
    }


    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) ->UIView {

        switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex
        {
        case 0:
                let chosenManagerScrollView: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(40,0,170,72))
                chosenManagerScrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
                var jumperCables: [String] = []
                for var i = 0; i < rejuvenatedEnterprisesEmployees.count ; ++i {
                    jumperCables.append(rejuvenatedEnterprisesEmployees[i].name)
                }
                chosenManagerScrollView.text = jumperCables[row]
                return chosenManagerScrollView
        case 1:
                let chosenManagerScrollView: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(40,0,170,72))
                chosenManagerScrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
                var jumperCablez: [String] = []
                for var i = 0; i < rejuvenatedEnterprisesVictorsEmployees.count ; ++i {
                    jumperCablez.append(rejuvenatedEnterprisesVictorsEmployees[i].name)
                }
                chosenManagerScrollView.text = jumperCablez[row]
                return chosenManagerScrollView
        default:
            print("done")
            let chosenManagerScrollView: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(40,0,170,72))
            chosenManagerScrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            var jumperCables: [String] = []
            for var i = 0; i < rejuvenatedEnterprisesEmployees.count ; ++i {
                jumperCables.append(rejuvenatedEnterprisesEmployees[i].name)
            }
            chosenManagerScrollView.text = jumperCables[row]
            return chosenManagerScrollView

        }
    }



    func displayEmployeeGroup(chosenEmployee: String, fromComponent chosenComponent: String) {

        switch chosenEmployee {
            case chosenEmployee where chosenEmployee == "Jeffrey Wells":
                for employee in rejuvenatedEnterprisesEmployees {
                    print(employee)
                    employeeListing.text = "\(employee)\n"
            }
            case chosenEmployee where chosenEmployee == "Victor Atkins":
            break

            case chosenEmployee where chosenEmployee == "Kelli Hamilton":
            break

        default: print("done")
        }
        if chosenEmployee == "Jeffrey Wells" {
            for employee in rejuvenatedEnterprisesEmployees {
                print(employee)
                employeeListing.text = "\(employee)\n"
            }
        }
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        let chosenEmployee: Int = pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(kManagerScrollComponent)
        displayEmployeeGroup(squaredEnterprisesEmployees[chosenEmployee], fromComponent: "the list of employees")
    }




    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Yes, the segmented control is not updating the UIPickerView with the array instantiated at the top of the class.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I see why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't understood how data source / delegate messaging works. This code doesn't do what you think it does:

```
case 0:
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) ->UIView {
```

That won't magically cause this function to be the data source `viewForRow` method. It merely defines a *local function* which comes into existence and vanishes again instantly, to no point. You must implement `viewForRow` at the top level of your view controller like all your other methods. *It* must make the choice based on the segment selected. (In fact I think you've already set that up.) The segmented control, when its value changes, then merely tells the picker view to reload (e.g. `reloadAllComponents`) and thus cause `viewForRow` to be called again.

Comment: totally understandable and thank you for that.  During that approach, can I implement the segmented control switch statement inside the viewForRow method?  Does that make sense what I'm saying?

Comment: You already have done that. That code is probably fine, though I have not actually looked at it beyond its general structure.

Comment: Thanks @matt, are you suggesting removing the viewForRow method from inside the UISegmentedControl IBAction method?  If so, how do we fire off the function to update the UIPickerView based on the UISegmentControl chosen?

Comment: Okay, so I've answered all that and you're not even reading what I wrote. _Read_ my answer. Read it carefully and thoroughly. _Think_ about what it says.

Comment: After reading again and if I understand correctly then I'll need to call pickerView.reloadAllComponents() from inside the viewForRow method that houses the switch statement for the UISegmentedControl